# Tracking my USB Copies from Bitlocker Device

Tags: bitlocker

I've a Bitlocker device. And I'm copying some file from this device to a Bitlocker To-Go encrypted USB. Can this copying be tracked by someone?

Also, now I'm copying material from the Bitlocker To-Go encrypted USB to another system. Can this second copy be tracked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you work for the corporation where there's File Auditing, tracking this file is possible, like when you have read the file in question. And it has nothing to do with bitlocker.

If the USB stick was provisioned by your company, then writing to this USB drive might also be tracked.

Now when you plug it to another system, assuming it's also corporate system, the situation is the same. If it's not corporate system, then this Auditing  will not work over internet to your company.

Answer (score 1):

> I've a bitlocker device. And I'm copying some file from this device to bitlocked USB. Can this copying be tracked by someone?

I'm assuming this refers to Bitlocker To-Go. In that case - no. There isn't any provision to allow this to happen.

> I'm copying material from bitlocked USB to another system. Can this second copy be tracked?

No, unless the files in question haven't been stripped of their metadata - which would allow any viewer to see the system that they originated from (the 'Author' name etc.) or if the files have executables embedded in them that allow their location to be traced.

Just open them on an airgapped system and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer! Since Aria's answer was more relevant to my situation I marked it as answer. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, glad you got your answer :)